# How to set parameter to a XCUITest test case do prepare for data driven testing

Tags: swift, xctest

Is it possible to have parameter for a test case like:

```
func testExample1(term: String) {

  XCTContext.runActivity(named: "Search for \(term)") { activity in
        // Enter text in the search field
    let textField = XCUIApplication().otherElements.containing(.button, identifier:"Button").children(matching: .textField).element
    textField.tap()
    textField.typeText(term)
  }
```

As soon as I change my test case to get parameter, the XCUItest change it from test case to class function.

I need to do the following call (or something like that):

```
xcodebuild test -project MyLib.xcodeproj -scheme MyAppUITests -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.3,name=iPhone 5s' -only-testing:MyAppUITests/MyAppUITests/testExample1("toto")|xcpretty --test --color
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, XCTest has no support for parameterized testing.

(Will that change at this year's WWDC? I keep hoping, every year…)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This mean XCTest is not data driven at all.
This is pretty weird, this is not mature framework unfortunately.
cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will ever be possible for XCTest :-). Anyway with the advent of Swift Macros, you can do very similar things in pure Swift. My colleague and I have developed a neat Swift Macro for parameterized XCTest. With this, you can simply use:

```
@Parametrize(input: ["some", "names", "toto"])
func testExample(input term: String) {
  ...
}
```

The macro will create a copy of your method for a given parameter set. So, of course, it's not exactly your scenario as you can't pass parameters during execution of the tests. Those need to be embedded in your source code. Nevertheless, data-driven testing is closer than before.

Check it out here: https://github.com/PGSSoft/XCTestParametrizedMacro